# Looking for regex to find footer elements

Tags: regex

I would like to use regex to search for all instances of a footer in a epub like the following sample:

```
<p class="calibre1">2  &lt;&gt;  GENERAL INTRODUCTION </p>
```

of the more general format:

```
<p class="calibre1">[page number from 1-1000]["  &lt;&gt;"][Title of section]</p>
```

My goal is to use calibre's regex to find all instances of that footer and delete them but I've tried these expressions and none of them work to even find the one above example:

```
<p class="calibre1">[0-9]  &lt;&gt;[^>] </p>
<p class="calibre1">[0-9]  &lt;&gt;  [\w] </p>
and even the general:
<p class="calibre1">[\w--[\d_]]</p>
<p class="calibre1">[0-9] [.]</p>
<p class="calibre1">[0-9] *[.]</p>
<p class="calibre1">[0-9][*.]</p>
```

I'm new to regex and am pulling my hair out. Please help with my (mis)understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for what you want:

```
^<p[ \t]*class="calibre1">[0-9]+[^<]*&lt;&gt;[^<]*<[/]p>$
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
^<p class="calibre1">\d{1,4}.*</p>$

^ - Anchor to the start of the line
<p class="calibre1"> - Actual text to match
\d{1,4} - match 1 to 4 digits
.* - then zero or more characters 
<\p> - until the closing tag
$ - anchored to the end of the line
```